# Adding hyperlink to cells in a For loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a For loop set up so that if the value in a cell = x, then a folder is created from cell values in the row, the folder is opened, and a word document is created from the data.

I'm trying to set it up so that it also creates a hyperlink in the cell in column D to the created folder.

Below is part of the code (ignores the rest of the `if` options), but I can't seem to get the section for creating the link to work.

```
Sub CreateLicenceFull()

Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc
   Dim objRange

Dim dirName As String
     On Error Resume Next
Dim Foldername As String

   r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)
           If .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
                dirName = Cells(4, i).Values
         MkDir ("\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", TextToDisplay:=.Value
         Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & """\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")""", vbNormalFocus)

                Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   objWord.Visible = True
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Mobile Plant\Mobile Plant Licence.docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("LicenceNo").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 4)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 29)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Company").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 7)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Address").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 8)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 13)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location2").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 12)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("From").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 18)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("To").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 19)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date2").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 29)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 34)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Title").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 35)

    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.SaveAs ("\\richmond\data\Environment\Traffic & Transport\T&T - NetworkManagement\Street Works 2019-20\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")

        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anchor takes a Range object, you are passing a integer**

Change your Anchor from:

```
Anchor:=r
```

**to:**

```
Anchor:= Cells(i, 5)
```

That should make it work.

**See Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Not displaying any error but isn't hyperlinking any cell either.

Comment: @ffc2004 .. Try Changing the line to `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 5), Address:="\\richmond\", TextToDisplay:="Link"`  .. See if this test works. Then you would know that there is a problem in your address formation.

Comment: Apologies, the whole time I'd been testing on the wrong section of code, so the value didn't match - it works perfectly now. Been looking at the code for so long it all merged into one!

Comment: Is there a way to enable hyperlinking protected cells?

Comment: You will have to unprotect the  sheet first.